# Ubuntu Edge: where to buy?

Tags: ubuntu-edge

I have been seeing in the news and in several reviews of the Ubuntu Edge "superphone" and I was just wondering how or where to buy the phone, I heard about indiegogo, but is that the only place in which I might be able to buy it, if not is the physical phone being bought from indiegogo?

Comment: Ubuntu Edge was a crowdfunded project that, unfortunately, didn't meet its funding goal. Therefore, the phone will not be manufactured (unless they ever decide to), and so your question is off-topic. Read more about Ubuntu Edge [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Edge).